# OverLoading : Ambigutiy while the parameters are primitive but not while it is Reference type

Tags: java, string, object, stringbuffer

```
public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {


    new Test().f("dfffg");   // it is running perfectly
    new Test().f(1, 1);      // it is giving ambiguity
}

public void f(int a,long b){
    System.out.println("in int and long");
}

public void f(long a,int b){
    System.out.println("in long and int");
}

public void f(String s) {
    System.out.println("in String");

}


public void f(StringBuffer o) {
    System.out.println("in String bufer");

}

public void f(Object o){
    System.out.println("in object");
}
}
```

when i execute this `new Test().f("dfffg");` it is running perfectly although we have overload method with StringBuffer and Object as parameter

while f(1,1) giving ambiguity, which I can understand.

Comment: int can be promoted to long if no matching datatype is found. This is causing function ambiguity. If you want to use both functions, you can use functions like f(int... a) and f(long... a). These are not solutions to your problem but can help in resolving ambiguity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Test().f("dfffg")` matches the signatures of both `public void f(String s)` and `public void f(Object o)`. When you are passing an object parameter, the method having the most specific argument type is chosen: in this case `public void f(String s)`. `String` is more specific than `Object` since `String` is a sub-class of `Object`.

`public void f(StringBuffer o)` is not relevant in this example, since a `StringBuffer` is not a super-class of `String`, so you can't pass a `String` to a method that expects a `StringBuffer`.

Comment: @sparsh610 I just edited the answer to account for that.